# How can i put 3 divs side by side with a margin and a border?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put three divs side by side which works fine but when i add a border and a small gap between each div the 3rd div goes onto a new line. Is there a way to auto resize the divs so they fit?

HTML:

```
  <div class="trendingContainer">
      <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox">
        <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending</h3> </div>
        123
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending</h3> </div>
        123
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending</h3> </div>
        123
      </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.trendingContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.trendingBox {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use calc and percentage based widths:

```
.trendingBox {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 4px);
}
```

If you want to support multiple browser widths separately you can use media queries:

```
@media(max-width: 600px) {
    .trendingBox {
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0 2px 0 0;
        width: calc(100% / 2 - 4px);
    }
}

@media(min-width: 601px) {
    .trendingBox {
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 0 2px 0 0;
        width: calc(100% / 3 - 4px);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which won't work in IE < 11. There are other solutions then 'calc'.

Comment: This worked good for me, less than 1% of my users are using < IE 11 anyway. Thanks

Comment: @JellePosthuma this is just one solution, if he wants to support IE<11, then he'll use something else, but those browsers are only mainly used in workplaces.

Comment: @Bálint - Just had a thought i think i want to show 2 boxes when it's on small browser, can i still use this method?

Comment: @Exxon in that case you need to change the `/ 3` to `/2`.

Comment: @Exxon use two media queries, where one uses 2 and one uses 3

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer, I've never done media queries before.

Comment: @Exxon sure, give me a minute

Comment: @Exxon Here you go

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `float` or `flex` model, but make sure you have `border-box` set. And when you are using `margin` along with a fixed layout like this, ensure the widths correctly:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.trendingContainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.trendingBox {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 0.5%
}
```

```html
<div class="trendingContainer">
  <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h3>Trending</h3>
    </div>
    123
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h3>Trending</h3>
    </div>
    123
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <div class="block-title">
      <h3>Trending</h3>
    </div>
    123
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: if when it gets to small browser size i want it to show 2 instead, then when it gets to browser size XS i just want 1 to show, Will this method still work?

Comment: @Exoon You can use `@media` queries mate!

Answer (score 0):

One more try, this time totally different, added a child DIV to specify the content with margin and border:

(This maintains the original sizing and other bootstrap stuff, only defines the additional styling on a separate div, which is more clean to use)

HTML:

```
<div class="trendingContainer">
    <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox">
        <div class="trendingBox-content">
            <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending</h3> </div>
            123
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="trendingBox-content">
            <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending</h3> </div>
            123
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="trendingBox-content">
            <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending</h3> </div>
            123
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.trendingContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.trendingBox {
    /* Add other style here */
}
.trendingBox-content{
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Theres a bigger gap between all the boxes when i use this method, Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

```
.trendingBox { 
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;  
    background: #fff; 
    margin: 0 2px 0 0; 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
}
```

1. calc is new in css3 I believe.
2. 4px is 2px(margin) + 2*1px(border)
3. Another thing you can try is using outline. I believe its width would is considered as a port of the box element, haven't tried though.

I believe rest all is clear

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```css
.trendingContainer {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.trendingBox {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="trendingContainer">
      <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox">
        <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending</h3> </div>
        123
      </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending Big</h3> </div>
        123
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 trendingBox hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <div class="block-title"><h3>Trending</h3> </div>
        123
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has no fixed width for any of the box. I just edited your answer to show why it doesn't work. Just check the middle box... `:)` You need to give width in percentages to get the right one...

Comment: Oh yeah. Just checked. Thanks for noticing. I had missed that out. Thank you. :) But i had just written a generic way of how it might be done. Adding width and number of boxes was something i had kept variable. But I'll keep that in mind, thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
.trendingBox {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The `box-sizing: border-box;` does the trick. This makes sure the div doesn't resize when adding padding to it.

**EDIT: See my other answer, which is the right way to do it in my opinion.**

Comment: Nope it doesn't. `margin` is unaffected.

Comment: Oh I read padding. My mistake. In that case I would leave the divs as they are, and put a child div in it which can have any style it wants without shifting the parent div.